# Is there a good add-on for RTL text support in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, software-recommendation, creative-cloud, arabic

I've found [this website](http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/photoshop-arabic/) where you have to write and paste (!) Arabic text for Photoshop, but I need a better one with more language abilities. Anything in mind?

Answer (score 4):

### [Enable Middle Eastern features](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/photoshop/using/arabic-hebrew.html)

> To reveal Middle Eastern type options in the Photoshop interface, do
>   the following:
>
> 1. Choose Edit > Preferences > Type (Windows) or Photoshop > Preferences > Type (Mac OS).
> 2. In the Choose Text Engine Options section, select Middle Eastern.
> 3. Click OK, and restart Photoshop.
> 4. Choose Type > Language Options > Middle Eastern features.

### Text direction

> To create content in Arabic and Hebrew, you can make the right-to-left
>   (RTL) direction the default text direction. However, for documents
>   that include left-to-right (LTR) text, you can now seamlessly switch
>   between the two directions.
>
> Select the paragraph direction from the Paragraph panel.

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option under the Type window

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to :

Photoshop > preferences > Type

Then you can see 2 buttons on the right side.

Select **"Middle Eastern and South Asian"**
and reopen photoshop. Then you can type RTL with no problem.

Comment: It doesn't always work, but that's the proper way of doing it.